# Jquery Ajax posting twice on input blur

Tags: jquery, ajax

Having some issues with my jquery Ajax call posting twice.

```
function ajaxCall() {
    this.send = function(data, url, method, success, type) {
    type = type || 'json';
    var successRes = function(data) {
          success(data);
      };
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: successRes,
            dataType: type,
            timeout: 60000,
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                //alert(xhr.status);
                console.log(thrownError);
                alert("Error could not retrieve the data");
            }
        });
      }
    }
```

Now this is how i'm updating the database when ever the user focusin and out of an input filed. posting works but it is make two calls which i do not want.

```
// input type boxes update function
$("input[type=text], input[type=checkbox], textarea, input[type=number]").focus(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    var key = $this.attr('name');
    var value = $this.val();
    var lookupTable = $this.attr('data-LookupTable');
    var method = "POST";

    $this.on('blur', function(){
        var call = new ajaxCall();
        var url = '/ajaxx/ajax.update.php';
        var newValue = $this.val();
            if (newValue!= value) {
                var data = {
                            'keyField' : key,
                            'keyValue' : newValue,
                            'lookupTable' : lookupTable
                    }
                call.send(data,url,method);
            };
    });
});
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears you may have the event firing twice for two different items. What is "$this" for for each call? Perhaps the textarea gets called after the text, checkbox etc blur is triggered?

Comment: don't use one event to bind another event unless you are prepared to remove it also. Will get into lots of problems compounding event handlers. There is no need for the `focus` event, it is not doing anything constructive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line:
$this.unbind('blur');
before your line:
$this.on('blur', function(){

regrads